# Нужна помощь с прогой на Python написанной с модулем tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, интерфейс

Есть код, написанный с помощью модуля tkinter, он запускает мелкую программку. В общем, мне нужно создать функцию которая будет очищать поле ввода текста. Я новичок, а если учитывать первый модуль с которым я работаю, то я вообще картофель, так что помогите пожалуйста. Кнопка под сброс уже заготовлена, мне нужна чисто функция, которую назовите как **reset** и в теории оно должно сразу заработать. Комментарии есть, так что думаю не заблудитесь.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox

# Создание главного окна:
root = tk.Tk()                      # Основное окно
root.title("Какое-то приложение")   # Название окна
root.geometry("400x250")            # Размер окна 
root.resizable(False,False)         # Запрет на изменение размеров окна
root.configure(bg="#d1ddde")        # Фон окна


# Создание виджетов:
entry = tk.Entry(root, width=30)    # Поле для ввода окна с шириной 30
entry.pack(pady=10)                 # Вывод на экран


# Функция выполняющая показ текста: 
def show_text():
    user_text = entry.get()
    messagebox.showinfo("Введённый текст", f"Вы ввели: {user_text}")

# Создание кнопки 
button1 = tk.Button(root, text="Нажми меня",    # Текст внутри кнопки
                   background="#9ce6bd",        # Цвет кнопки
                   font=("Helvetica", 16),      # Шрифт и размер шрифта
                   command=show_text)           # Выполнение функции при нажатии
button1.pack(pady=10)                           # Вывод на экран

button2 = tk.Button(root, text="Сброс",     # Текст внутри кнопки
                   background="#DB7093",    # Цвет кнопки
                   font=("Helvetica", 16),  # Шрифт и размер шрифта
                   command=reset)           # Выполнение функции при нажатии
button2.pack(pady=20)                       # Вывод на экран

# Запуск цикла приложения:
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2260355/15035314